# Determine the values of the following function is a natural cubic spline.

Tags: mathematical-modeling, spline

$$s(x)=\begin{cases}
3+ax-9x^2+bx^3,\quad &1\le x\le 2\\
1+c(x-2)+d(x-2)^2+t(x-2)^3, &2\le x\le 3
\end{cases} $$

This is what I have:
$$\begin{cases}
s_1= bx^3-9x^2+ax+3 &s_2= t(x-2)^3+d(x-2)^2+c(x-2)+1\\
s_1'=3bx^2-18x+a & s_2'= 3t(x-2)^2+2d(x-2)+c\\
s_1''=6bx-18 & s_2''= 6t(x-2)+2d\\
\end{cases}$$

Then when we have $s_1(2),  s_2(2)$:

$$\begin{cases}
s_1(2) &= 8b+2a-33\\
s_1^\prime(2) &= 12b-36+a\\
s_1^{\prime \prime}(2) &= 12b-18
\end{cases}$$
and for $s_2(2)$:
$$\begin{cases}
s_2(2) &= 1\\
s_2^\prime(2) &= c\\
s_2^{\prime \prime}(2) &= 2d
\end{cases}$$
 and $s_2''(3)=0 \rightarrow 6t+2d=0$
I'm stuck in the next step, do I have it set up right?
edit: would I have to solve for $s_1''(1)=0$

Comment: In computing $s_1',$ how did $a$ become $9?$ Do you know that $a=9?$ Also, as is typical in spline situations, you have more unknowns (5) than equations (4). Do you have a preference for the kind of spline you're doing?

Comment: just figured i messed that one up, let me edit it, but we are going to use the natural cubic spline.

Comment: Right, so you're also going to need $s_1''(1)=0$ to finish setting up the natural spline boundary conditions. Then set up your system of equations, and you're off to the races.